# Skolem Functions vs Elementary Equivalence

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory

I am just curious about something. I think this is trivially true, but I wanted to be sure.

Suppose we have two elementary equivalent $\mathcal{L}$-structures $\mathfrak{A}$ and $\mathfrak{B}$. Also, suppose $\text{Th}(\mathfrak{A})$ has built-in Skolem functions, namely, for all $\mathcal{L}$-formulas $\phi(v,w_1,\cdots,w_n)$ there is a function symbol $f$ such that $\text{Th}(\mathfrak{A})\vDash \forall \bar{w} ((\exists v \phi(v,\bar{w}))\rightarrow \phi(f(\bar{w}),\bar{w}))$. Can we say the same for $\mathfrak{B}$, in this case?

Comment: The answer to your question is yes, but where you're coming from does not sound right. What do you mean by "$\mathfrak A$ is well-ordered, so $\operatorname{Th}(\mathfrak A)$ naturally has Skolem functions"?

Comment: @tomasz   I'm not familiar with these definitions, so I couldn't be sure. But you're right, this is obviously true. In a well-ordered structure, we can take $f(\bar{w})$ as the least $w$ such that $\mathfrak{A}\vDash \phi(w,\bar{w})$ if it exists.

Comment: I don't claim that it is obviously true. Quite the opposite: the condition you suggest is not first order definable.

Comment: And on a related note, this is far less serious, but you seem to be confusing having built-in Skolem functions and having definable Skolem functions.

Comment: @tomasz Thanks for the comment. I'm not sure why this is false.  If there is $v$ such that $\mathfrak{A}\vDash \phi(v,\bar{w})$, then the set $\{a\in A: \mathfrak{A}\vDash \phi(a,\bar{w})\}$ is nonempty, so we can take its minimum. Maybe I'm confused the different terms as you said. If you clarify the problem, I would be glad.

Comment: @tomasz I read the same in https://www.math.uci.edu/~mzeman/M281F10/lect-gilula-100506.pdf , Prop. 2.7.

Comment: @tomasz By the way, when I said "it is obviously true", I meant the answer of my question.

Comment: The proposition you are referring to is in ZF. It only says that Skolem functions exist (which, in ZFC, is a given), which is quite a long way from the Skolem functions being built-in or definable. I also don't think it is an elementary property (unless you have axiom of choice, in which case the property is trivial).

Comment: @tomasz I see now what you mean, and yes, I should said we are in ZFC. My problem is to confuse Skolem functions and Skolem functions being built-in. Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Specifically, by elementary equivalence the **same function symbols** serve as Skolem functions in $\mathfrak{B}$: "$\forall\overline{w}((\exists v\phi(v,\overline{w}))\rightarrow\phi(f(\overline{w}),\overline{w}))$" is a first-order sentence, so if it's true in $\mathfrak{A}$ it's true in $\mathfrak{B}$.

Comment: Thanks, I thought the same but I wasn't sure. This is actually an obvious fact.